# How to add notification in Ruby on Rails applicatioon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have application build with Ruby on Rails, you can see it here: [Sidodi](https://pure-caverns-34180.herokuapp.com/).

This app has 2 models, User and OutgoingMail. The OutgoingMail model has status that can change from draft to final.

It has 3 user role:

1. Conseptor
2. Head of division
3. Head of office

The workflow is:

1. Conceptor create new OutgoingMail the default status is draft
2. Conceptor send the OutgoingMail and status change to draft-1
3. Head of division check the OutgoingMail
4. Head of division send the OutgoingMail and status change to draft-2
5. Conceptor view and change the OutgoingMail
6. Conceptor send the OutgoingMail revision and status change to draft-3
7. Head of division check the OutgoingMail
8. Head of division send the OutgoingMail and status change to draft-4
9. Conceptor view and change the OutgoingMail
10. Conceptor send the OutgoingMail revision and status change to draft-5
11. Head of office check the OutgoingMail
12. Head of office send the OutgoingMail and status change to draft-6
13. Conceptor view and change the OutgoingMail
14. Conceptor send the OutgoingMail revision and status change to draft-7
15. Head of office check the OutgoingMail
16. Head of office send the OutgoingMail and status change to final
17. Conceptor view, change, download, and print the OutgoingMail

When i push the send button, the status changed but i need to push refresh (F5) to view the OutgoingMail. It happened when the different role view the page but the OutgoingMail unseen until pushing refresh button (F5).

Is there any way to create notification in Ruby on Rails application?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rails' [flash notifications](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DanKreiger, i have add the code to create method that say "Outgoing Mail successfully created", but the problem is the view for conceptor is updated but the view for Head of Division not updated automatic. I want to give the Head of Division notification about Outgoing Mail that has created and send by the Conceptor. Any idea about this?